# App crashes when using Content Resolver and Content Provider

Tags: android, mysql

I have an activity class which uses the ContentResolver's `query()` method with `Uri & projection[]` being set as two of its arguments and rest are set as 'null'.
Like:

`ContentResolver resolverCatalog = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = resolverCatalog.query(PetsEntry.CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,null);`

However in the ContentProvider class the `query()` method is defined as:

```
 @Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    // Making an instance of the SQLiteOpenHelper class named as 'SQLdbHelper'
    SQLdbHelper PetdbHelper = new SQLdbHelper(getContext());

    //getting access to database
    SQLiteDatabase database_query = PetdbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    // This cursor will hold the result of the query
    Cursor cursor_query;

    // Figure out if the URI matcher can match the URI to a specific code
    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match) {
        case PETS:
            cursor_query = database_query.query(TABLE_NAME,projection,null,null,null,null,null);
            break;

        case PET_ID:
            selection = PetContract.PetsEntry._ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri)) };

            // This will perform a query on the pets table where the _id equals 3 to return a
            // Cursor containing that row of the table.
            cursor_query = database_query.query(TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null, null, sortOrder);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot query unknown URI " + uri);
    }

    return cursor_query;
}
```

The PETS & PETS_ID are defined (within this ContentProvider class) as:

```
public class PetProvider extends ContentProvider {

//object made of the helper class for the provider, to get access of the database
private SQLdbHelper PetdbHelper;


private static final int PETS = 1;
private static final int PET_ID = 2;

private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

static {
    sUriMatcher.addURI(CONTENT_AUTHORITY, PATH_PETS, PETS);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(CONTENT_AUTHORITY, PATH_PETS_ID, PET_ID);
}...//class continues
```

In the `AndroidManifest` I've wrote:

```
 <provider
        android:name=".data.PetProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.petsretry.data"
        android:exported="false">
 </provider>
```

Have tried multiple things over it but couldn't get out of it...Please help!
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You should post a stack trace of the running application when it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Have found the solution, problem was with the Android Manifest file, correct code is:

```
<provider android:name=".data.PetProvider" android:authorities="com.example.android.petsretry.data" android:exported="false"/>
```

All 'name', 'authorities' and 'exported' property should have been inside the opening tag of the provider instead of being in between the opening & closing tag of provider...
Hoof...